# Truman's use of 'become' in 'it becomes my duty' ? (1951 US)

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

> [[Source:]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_Truman%27s_relief_of_General_Douglas_MacArthur#Relief) 
>   On 11 April 1951, President Truman drafted an order to MacArthur, which was issued under Bradley's signature:
>
> I deeply regret that it **becomes** my duty as President and Commander-in-Chief of the United States military forces to replace you as Supreme Commander, Allied Powers; Commander-in-Chief, United Nations Command; Commander-in-Chief, Far East; and Commanding General, U.S. Army, Far East.
>
> **[become](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/become)** = 1. [no object, with complement] Begin to be:

I'm not that knowledgeable of US history, but when Truman (or Bradley) wrote this letter, did the US President already hold this duty to replace a General?

If so, then is this use of **to become** wrong? Such use wrongly means that Truman only began to hold this duty precisely at the moment that he (or Bradley) wrote this

Comment: It "became" necessary to replace him, and therefore it became his duty **at that time**.

Comment: I would have used "has become" rather than "becomes" but both are grammatical.

Comment: Truman's intended meaning of *become* is the fourth one listed [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/become?s=t): "to be suitable or necessary to the dignity, situation, or responsibility of." 

Truman is expressing to MacArthur that he is regretful/apologetic about replacing him, but the duties/responsibilities of his position (President) require him to do so.

Refer to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conduct_unbecoming_an_officer_and_a_gentleman) for an expression that uses *become* in the same way.

Comment: [Another example](http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1918/02/25/page/5/article/goldman-and-berkman-links-in-indian-plot) of *become* as I analyze Truman to have used it: "I cannot force myself to the conviction that I am capable of making war on my kindred upon their soil in a manner that would become my duty and station." - Capt. David A. Henkes, quoted in *The Chicago Daily Tribune*, February 25, 1918

Comment: @pyobum That's a very good example, and I think your point about Truman not choosing the present perfect bears thought. I'll think about this. (Right now, though, it behooves me to get some work done.)

Comment: @BenKovitz I see how it can potentially have either one of the meanings we've suggested. I think the meaning I've proposed has fallen out of use and that the scope of its usage was fairly narrow even 60+ years ago. Unfortunately, resurrecting Truman so we can ask him directly probably isn't an option, and even if it were, I doubt our grammar questions would be very well received. Think it over! Cheers.

Comment: @pyobum - I think your two comments really should be folded into an answer.

Comment: @pyobum That is another good point: that usage has changed since Truman's time. That might even be a useful lead for some historical information to make clear which reading is most faithful to Truman's use of the word.

Comment: @J.R. I had posted an answer more or less saying what's in my above comments (perhaps too concisely) that almost immediately got two "drive-by" downvotes, so I pulled it. If I get another couple of people backing up my analysis and examples in the comments, I'll expand my original answer and repost it. On a side note, I think that it would be useful to also ask this question on English Language and Usage (with a "meaning" tag) and that it would get some good answers/analysis from the users there.

Comment: @pyobum - Maybe the original answer was a bit too concise. At any rate, cross-posting on both ELL and ELU is discouraged, so I hope that doesn't happen.

Comment: @J.R. That's good information for the future. I wasn't clear on the general feeling towards cross-posting. Any chance of it being migrated? Or do you think it's better off staying here on ELL?

Comment: @pyobum - Yes, cross-posting is discouraged across all of SE, although many SE sites so overlap somewhat (like [elu.se] and [writers.se], for example, or [cs.se] and [datascience.se]). As for migrating it, I don't think _"Is this usage of_ become _wrong?"_ is really a question that needs to be handled by "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts." It's an interesting question, as some of your comments point out, but it's fine right here.

Answer (score 1):

**Becomes** is correct.

Indeed Truman already had the duty to oversee the military, including appointing the highest generals. He held that duty all the time he was president.

When he says "It becomes my duty", he means that in his judgement, his general duty to oversee the military *now* specifically includes firing MacArthur, because of the present situation.

Here is another example of the same thing. A police officer's duties include arresting people suspected of crimes. When Wayne Thompson was sworn in as a police offer, he assumed that duty. But he did not have a duty at that time to arrest Walter Finch, because Walter Finch wasn't suspected of a crime at that time. Several months later, when Wayne Thompson saw Walter Finch breaking into a house, it *became Wayne Thompson's duty* to arrest him.

Comment: You (and other answerers) are misinterpreting the meaning of "become" in the quote. Compare it to the use of "become" in the common military expression "[conduct unbecoming an officer and a gentleman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conduct_unbecoming_an_officer_and_a_gentleman)."

Comment: @pyobum I don't think that's the intended meaning. I could be wrong, of course. Do you know of any information that would enable us to tell which of the two theories is right? My own reasoning is just (1) that "becoming"'s meaning of "suitable to" has a connotation of desirability and seemliness that doesn't fit with Truman's act or situation; it's not something to regret. And (2) the meaning of "turning into my duty" easily makes sense here, and is something Truman would deeply regret having to do.

Comment: See my new comment above. It has the same meaning as "[behoove](https://www.google.com/#q=behoove+definition)" when used in this way. Truman's statement could be rephrased as, "It *is a required part of* my duty as President..." On a personal level, Truman doesn't want to replace MacArthur. As President, he has to do it. If he were simply saying that replacing MacArthur is *now* his duty (but wasn't before), why wouldn't he have used present perfect: "It **has** become my duty..."?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing an **office** with the *duties* it requires one to perform.

Truman holds an office which obliges him to perform certain duties *as they arise.*

Thus, Truman is referring to a particular duty/action which he must *now* perform, or that *has become* necessary for him to perform.

The M-W gives one of the main definitions of duty:
**duty**
obligatory tasks, conduct, service, or functions enjoined by order or usage according to rank, occupation, or profession (*duties that he knew he would have to do— Joseph Conrad*)

The phrase *it becomes my duty* is almost a stock phrase, or at least it was. Google-book the phrase and you will see dozens of instances of it. Most often with regard to an office or obligation that one has or holds.

As for *become*, it can mean to *befit*, *be proper to*. But this meaning does not fit. I suggest you check dictionarie**s** to see that this definition almost always has a *person* as its object. This sweater becomes me. Or it refers to an *action* that is unbecoming to some*one*. But not unbecoming to something.

Answer (score 0):

The subject '**it**' refers forward to a **'to'-infinitive clause** or **a finite subordinate clause**

***It*** costs so much **to get there**.

***It*** becomes my duty **to replace you** as Supreme Commander.

***It*** was amazing **that audiences came to the theater at all**.

Comment: But I'm not sure that replacing *it* with *to replace you* resolves the issue that the OP asks about.

Comment: @δοῦλος Thank you. Alas, I also don't believe that this answer my questions.